# Are NPRMs published in the Federal Register?

Tags: faa-regulations

Are FAA NPRMs (Notices of Proposed Rulemaking) published in the Federal Register?

I am currently researching the history of some airspace rule changes from the early 1990's, and am trying to figure out whether searching the Federal Register will turn up NPRMs, or only the resulting Final Rules.

For instance a "Terminal Airspace Reconfiguration NPRM", which is referenced on page 38963 of the Federal Register Volume 57 # 167 (Thursday August 27 1992).

Answer (score 1):

Since posting my question, I've learned that the answer is "yes".  For example, the following URL opens to a FAA NPRM published in the Federal Register: https://www.federalregister.gov/citation/57-FR-18954

Comment: Truth is this whole question was kind of a brain fart, over the past several years I have located several NPRMs in the Federal Register, but then I just forgot.

Comment: @ymb1 -  comments cleared